# Transform Pandas - How to make more efficient and fast

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following head of a dataframe in pandas.

**Input:**

```
IP Cnt  Loc
101 200 VA
102 300 VA
103 400 VT
103 400 CA
104 140 FL
```

I have the following code to create new columns - but this code takes forever to run on my dataset. I suspect the transform function is computationally expensive. Is there another way to get unique counts for a grouping in a more efficient way?

```
df['UniqueCnts'] = df.groupby('IP')['Cnt'].transform(lambda x: x.unique())
df['UniqueLocs'] = df.groupby('IP')['Loc'].transform(lambda x: x.unique())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just check `nunique`

```
df['UniqueCnts'] = df.groupby('IP')['Cnt'].transform('nunique')
```

Comment: Or even both at once with: `df[['UniqueCnts', 'UniqueLocs']] = df.groupby('IP').transform('nunique')`